# What can I do to help this batch script work normally?

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I am making ascii art with batch but the script closed immediately after I run it. I tried to escape "!", " | ", and " * " but it didn't seem to work, what can I do now?
Code:

```
@echo off                                                                      
echo   .  .  .         *    `o`o`                   
echo  . \ ^|/ .            o`o`o`o      ^^,^^,^              
echo  .__\:/__.             `o`o`     ^^,^^,^^,^^,^           
echo    .'^;`.         ._. ! ._.              .__\:/__.                   
echo                    ._\!/_.                 .'^;`.                 
echo *.''.:               ':'     :    '..'.* *-^=:o:^=- '      
echo :_\/_:'.:::.  * '*''      '.\'/.'   *_\)/_'.':'.'              
echo : /\ : :::::*   *_\/_* * -^= o ^=-*   /)\    '                  
echo  '..'* ':::'    * /\      .'/.\'. *  *   '           
echo         *  *     * ..      * : *      
pause
```

Comment: the code as posted is working as should be expected. The cmd window will not remain open if the batch is run by clicking on the batch file. for it to stay open, it has to be run from the command prompt. Alternately use `cmd /k` at the end of the script to keep command prompt open.

Comment: Oh, I may have fixed something when I was editing the script to post here

Comment: The only character you need to escape in your ASCII art is the `^` (given you have delayed expansion disabled, which is anyway the default). Open the batch file by opening a Command Prompt window, manoeuvring to its path (using `cd /D`) and typing its name rather than by double-clicking its icon, so you can read potential error messages (unless you have not put a plain `exit` in your script to quit it)…

Comment: The characters you've posted which require escaping are `|` and `^`, obviously when you're designing your 'art' in the editor, you will need to remember that those additional characters will make you image look wrong in that editor. The best advice to give is that you design it, then add the escape characters when you're happy with the design. Additional advice, which does not apply to the actual content above, _(because you've added many unnecessary trailing space characters to the end of each line)_, is you'll need to escape any 'art' `^` which ends a line, to stop it escaping the line end.

Comment: Oh, I did not spot the `|` which needs to be escaped too – sorry…

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an open Question, and I like to see things closed, so here's how to do it...

```
::: -------------------- More DOS Art ------------------------
:::
:::    .  .  .         *    `o`o`                   
:::   . \ ^|/ .            o`o`o`o      ^^,^^,^              
:::   .__\:/__.             `o`o`     ^^,^^,^^,^^,^           
:::     .'^;`.         ._. ! ._.              .__\:/__.                   
:::                     ._\!/_.                 .'^;`.                 
:::  *.''.:               ':'     :    '..'.* *-^=:o:^=- '      
:::  :_\/_:'.:::.  * '*''      '.\'/.'   *_\)/_'.':'.'              
:::  : /\ : :::::*   *_\/_* * -^= o ^=-*   /)\    '                  
:::   '..'* ':::'    * /\      .'/.\'. *  *   '           
:::          *  *     * ..      * : *      
:::
::: ---------------------- Fireworks -------------------------
for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do @echo(%%A
```